# What's the proper way in architecture design to avoid UI API to be called on a background thread?

Tags: swift, macos

In a MacOS app, I have a callback function called by another module (which is a network module that gets some response from the Internet to fire the callback):

```
func callbackHandler() {
    someViewController.updateSomeView()
}
```

In this callback handler, a view controller is called to update some view, and inside the view controller, reload data for a table:

```
func updateSomeView() {
    someTable.reloadData()
}
```

However, by doing so, I will get an error like this:

```
Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: ...
```

Therefore, I have to add `DispatchQueue.main.async()` either in the caller :

```
func callbackHandler() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async() {
        someViewController.updateSomeView()
    }
}
```

or the callee:

```
func updateSomeView() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async() {
        someTable.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Either way will solve the problem. But I think it's quite weird for the caller or the callee to be aware of that UI API called is going to be called on a background thread by adding `DispatchQueue.main.async()` as a fix.

How to do it in a proper way in terms of design architecture?

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing, and the API, is perfectly reasonable. It is quite normal for asynchronous callbacks to arrive on a background thread (esp. in connection with networking), and for the callee to have to step out to the main thread in order to touch the user interface. Don't worry, be happy.