# Swift - How to update UILabel from a function

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, uilabel, cbperipheral

i'm making a bluetooth app and i want to put 2 labels to control if i'm connected and to display the RSSI so i have write this function

```
func updateLabel(){
    LRSSI.text = String(RSSINb)
    if(Connected == true){
        LEtat.text = "Connected"
        LEtat.textColor = UIColor.green
    }else{
        LEtat.text = "Disconnected"
        LEtat.textColor = UIColor.red
    }
}
```

I call this function inside my ReadRSSI function from CBPeripheral.
There is this text in my terminal

```
Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UILabel setText:]
```

But when i rotate my phone it update labels, i tried to put 'self' before my labels.

 I also tried to call my function inside a timer but it gives me a SIGBART error
So is there a method to update labels or to reload viewcontroller ?

EDIT :
Call of my function:

```
 func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didReadRSSI RSSI: NSNumber, error: Error?) {
    print(RSSI)
    peripheral.readRSSI()

    RSSINb = Int(RSSI) * -1
    updateLabel()
    if(RSSINb > 150){
        WriteValue(valeur: "z")
    }
}
```

EDIT :

[What's the proper way in architecture design to avoid UI API to be called on a background thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47066259/whats-the-proper-way-in-architecture-design-to-avoid-ui-api-to-be-called-on-a-b)

Comment: Show the function that calls `updateLabel`. Clearly you need to change it so it is called on the main queue.

Comment: i have edited it @rmaddy

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47066259/whats-the-proper-way-in-architecture-design-to-avoid-ui-api-to-be-called-on-a-b and [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=2&tab=Relevance&q=Main%20Thread%20Checker%3a%20UI%20API%20called%20on%20a%20background%20thread%20%5bswift%5d) related to the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved:

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didReadRSSI RSSI: NSNumber, error: Error?) {
    print(RSSI)
    peripheral.readRSSI()

    RSSINb = Int(RSSI) * -1
    DispatchQueue.main.sync {
        updateLabel()
    }
    if(RSSINb > 150){
        WriteValue(valeur: "z")
    }
}
```